# .htaccess file causes "500 Internal Server Error" but no error log entry

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I set up an apache manually and added a second web directory with this code:

```
Alias /webs c:\webs
<Directory /webs>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

However, this web has an .htaccess file in it and accessing the website gives the error: "500 Internal Server Error", but does not write anything in the error log file.

But when I remove the .htaccess file, I don't get this error.

I added the "AllowOverride All" line and restarted the server but this doesn't correct the error.

My .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]

<Files "test">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

What do I have to do so that I can use an .htaccess file in this directory?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `<Files "test">` ?

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite in Apache web server. Also try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]

    <Files "test">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

If mod_rewrite is enabled then initiates the rewrite engine; else it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed this, it turned out to be two other issues, which I'll record here just in case it helps someone:

In my **php.ini** file, I had to set:

```
display_errors = On
```

so that it would display errors (even though I had "error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT").

Then the error was that I was trying to use RedBean with SQLite and needed to uncomment these in my **php.ini** file:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```